# Getting a user from database inside view

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

database: Firebase

A user is able to add a post which looks a bit like:

```
postKey
  content: 'Content of the post',
  date: 'Date of post',
  author: 'authorKey' (author key is a login)
```

I think I shouldn't store all user information inside `author` because user someday would change something in his profile. I store just user key inside `author` and I'd like to get that user while printing post data inside view.

(service)
That's the way I'm getting all posts (works correctly)

```
  getPosts(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve) => {
        this.af.database.list('/posts')
          .subscribe(response => {
            if(response.length > 0) resolve(response);
          })
      }
    )
  }
```

(component) Here I just assaign all these posts to posts array to print it inside view.

```
  posts: any;

  constructor(private homepageService: HomepageService) {
    homepageService.getPosts().then(
      response => {
        this.posts = response.reverse();
      });
  }
```

(view) Except all post data which I can print very easily, I'd like to get a user by post.author to print author data such as photo, firstname, surname, etc.

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts" class="post-body">
    {{post.content}}
    {{homepageService.getUser(post.author)?.email}}
</div>
```

In this way I'd like to get the user. Here is getUser function

```
  getUser(key): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(
      (resolve) => {
        this.af.database.object('/users/' + key)
          .subscribe(response => {
            resolve(response);
          })
      }
    );
  }
```

I know that line is wrong `{{homepageService.getUser(post.author)?.email}}` that there is no `then` inside view but I have tried also using async pipe. Now I am at a standstill. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{(homepageService.getUser(post.author) | async)?.email}}
```

or

```
{{(homepageService.getUser(post.author) | async).email}}
```

with

```
  getUser(key): Observable<any> {
    return this.af.database.object('/users/' + key);
  }
```

Comment: In that case my page crashes. Posts are not displayed and I can't do anything, can't click. All is frozen. (no errors in console). As I read ```this is expected behavior, because each time the method is called, you're returning a new instance of the promise, which when resolved, triggers change detection, which retrieves a new promise, which triggers change detection....```

Comment: What if you return the observable you get from the database call directly? (see my updated answer)